# Reference or proof for an integral inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, integral-inequality

The following seems believable and quasi-intuitive to me, but it also doesn't quite seem trivial, and I'm not sure whether I've seen it stated before.

Let $f$ be a complex-valued integrable function on $[a,b]$. We then have
$$
\left|\int_a^b f(x) dx\right| \le \int_a^b |f(x)| dx
$$
and furthermore (this is the part I care more about) the inequality is an equality if and only if
$$
f(x) = e^{ic}|f(x)| \qquad \mbox{almost everywhere, where $c$ is a constant.}
$$
Speaking very informally, if the integral of $f(x)$ "adds up" to have the same modulus as the integral of $|f(x)|$, it seems like this could only happen if $f(x)$ always "points the same way", i.e. if $f(x)$ maintains the same argument (almost everywhere).

My questions are: 1. Does anyone know a reference for this fact? (And does it have a name)? 2. Does it have a simple self-contained proof? (Or would a proof from more fundamental principles be somewhat involved, approximating an integral with a sum and so forth?)

Comment: The first inequality is proved easily by looking at the Riemann sum for the left side and applying triangle inequality.

Comment: Yeah, the first inequality is pretty straightforward. I'm more interested in the conditions under which the inequality is an equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that this is complex valued is not actually useful; this is more generally true in inner product spaces, so let's prove it there. In particular, let
$$v=\int_{a}^bf(x)\,dx.$$
and let $\hat{v}$ be the unit vector in the same direction as $v$. Notice that the left side of your inequality is then $\hat{v}\cdot v=\|v\|$. Thus, we have that your inequality is the same as (bringing the dot product inside the integral by linearity)
$$\int_{a}^b\hat v \cdot f(x)\,dx\leq \int_{a}^b|f(x)|\,dx$$
But this is obvious because $\hat v \cdot f(x) \leq |f(x)|$ for all $x$. Then, in order to obtain equality, you obviously need that $\hat v \cdot f(x) = |f(x)|$ for almost all $x$, as if there were a set of positive measure for which it were less, the former integral would be less too. This is essentially what your condition stated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. A small quibble: $\hat{v}$ is a complex number and $f$ is complex-valued, so a priori, $\hat{v} \cdot f(x)$ could be a complex number, so we have to be careful about inequalities containing it.

But I think it's salvageable. Split $\hat{v} \cdot f(x)$ into real and imaginary parts. Integrate real and imaginary parts separately. We know the imaginary part integrates to zero. Then, use an inequality involving the real part of $\hat{v} \cdot f(x)$.

Comment: @idmercer Yeah, though it seems that your modification is a bit overkill; essentially, that method would be to, if $v=\alpha(x+yi)$ where $x^2+y^2=1$, let $g(a+bi) = ax + by$, which is a linear (over $\mathbb R$) function $\mathbb C\rightarrow\mathbb R$, and hence distributes over the integral, and has $g(z)\leq |z|$. We don't need to appeal to any property of $\mathbb C$, other than that, as a normed vector space, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ with the Euclidean norm.